# What's the proper way to return a result from an activity to a specific view?

Tags: android, android-fragments, onactivityresult

New to Android. Trying to understand the technical downside of a design.

I have an `ItemSelectorView` which has both an `availableItems` collection as well as a `selectedItem` property. The latter is displayed at runtime along with a chevron letting the user know they can change it.

Functionality-wise, it's similar to a spinner except rather than showing a pop-up with the choices, it launches a second activity called `ItemSelectorActivity` which shows all of the available items from the `ItemSelectorView` which launched it, as well as helpful information about what each option means as well as the ability to search and filter.

When a user selects one, their choice is then returned back to the originating `ItemSelectorView` via a trip through `MainActivity`'s `onActivityResult` override.  The override then figures out which `ItemSelectorView` it's responding to and forwards it along.

However, I really didn't like the way `MainActivity` had to insert itself into the process just to get the result from `ItemSelectorActivity`. Plus, if `ItemSelectorView` was used in a fragment, things become more complex trying to forward the information to the correct view.

Because of this, I instead changed `ItemSelectorView` to `ItemSelectorFragment` which can override its own `onActivityResult` making it, not its owning activity, responsible for updating itself with the selected result. This means it's essentially completely self-contained now.

While this seems to work wonderfully--with this change a user only needs to place the `ItemSelectorFragment` somewhere in their layout and set the available and selected items--a veteran Android developer here said using a fragment like that was wrong and I should have stayed with a view because of the overhead of fragments.

But going back to a view means I'm back to having to get `MainActivity` involved again, making this much more complex to actually use.

So what is the technical down-side for using fragments like this? I thought that was the entire point of why they exist.  And if I am supposed to use a view, is there an easier way to get a result from `ItemSelectorActivity`?

Comment: OnActivityResult is used when you need in ActivityA info from ActivityB, if you want your activityB fresh itself, you can do it without the onActivityResult

Comment: There's also an onActivityResult in fragments.  Plus, as mentioned, ActivityA doesn't need the result.  A view in ActivityA does. For that reason, ActivityA doesn't even need to be aware of what's going on, and in the case of using a fragment as described, doesn't.

Comment: I get it wrong, for view you mean Fragment? If yes, then you can do it without the onActivityResult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, your view is starting an activity (`ItemSelectorView` starts `ItemSelectorActivity`). But views should be dump in Android. They should display, nothing more.

So a view should never start an activity. A view can contain a list of items maybe, but these items should be views and nothing else. Usually we use an `Adapter` for that: a middle man between the items to be displayed and the views that are created to represent them on the screen.

You could look into MVP to do this in a proper way. Or maybe MVVM and android architecture, if you like that better.

To answer your question, using a fragment for your use case is a better approach then a view and there is not that much overhead at all.

Comment: Re: "Display, nothing more." and 'Not start an activity' I disagree, but only a little. In this case, the selector activity can be considered part of the ItemSelectorView's UI. It just happens to be an activity, but it's also an activity that is only ever used *by* that ItemSelectorView. Nowhere else.  Think of this more like a spinner where the choices are in another activity. And while it displays the data, it doesn't own it.  The (view)model does. That's why the view can be dumped without issue as it would simply rehydrate it when it comes back up as expected.

Comment: I was more asking about the pure comm from the selection activity back to the view on the original activity, again, the same way a spinner's picker updates the spinner, which then updates the model. That aside, it sounds like this too backs up my desire to use a Fragment instead of a view which is what I was after. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, forgot to add, the ItemSelectorView doesn't need an adapter itself as it doesn't show the options. It just holds an array of what they are (but again doesn't own it.)  The ItemSelectorActivity however does use an adapter as it's responsible for displaying that collection, which is handed to it from the ItemSelectorView.  But ultimately the model owns everything and is responsible for setting those properties, the same as setting 'text' or 'background' or anything else. In this case, rather than a string, it's just an array.

Comment: yes, a fragment is the best solution for you it seems